# How to find lines in file containing set of special characters?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I am writing a script that runs through an existing `c` program and finds whether it contains comments:

They should start and end in comment tags:

```
/* and */
```

How can I achieve this?

Example:
This works:

```
egrep "/\.*\./" sample.txt
```

But i want to list the lines that start and end with /* / only, for example consider this input: hi / */ hello ; this is not a valid comment but its gonna be in the output when your command is used.

Comment: What are "double" comments? Do you mean something like `/* /* foo */ */`? Please [edit] your question and add an example of your input file, indicating what lines you want to match and what lines shouldn't.

Comment: @terdon yes i mean that but i would like to know for the simple case of /* */  and i can extend that to double comment

Comment: OK, as I said, please [edit] your question and include an example.

Comment: single line or multi-line ?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant single line

Answer (score 1):

To find lines containing `/*` and `*/`, all you need is

```
grep '/\*.*\*/' file
```

To find lines that start with `/*` and end with `*/`, use:

```
grep '^/\*.*\*/$' file
```

And to allow whitespace before the start comment and after the end, use:

```
grep -E '^\s*/\*.*\*/\s*$' file
```

Since the `*` is a special character, you need to escape it (`\*`). Apart from that, everything else is just a regular character. The regex above will match  `/*`, than 0 or more characters (`.*`) until a `*/`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i want to list the lines that start and end with /* */ only, for example consider this input: hi /* */ hello ; this is not a valid comment but its gonna be in the output when your command is used. How do i handle this?

Comment: @KLMM yes, well, that's precisely why I asked you, twice, to edit your question and give us examples.

Comment: so sorry will do now

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use sed:

#### sed 's%.*/*.**/%%; /^$/d'

For example to remove the comments:

```
printf "hello\nx=1\n/* some comment */\nnot some comment\nthis has /* but no close\n" |
sed 's%.*/\*.*\*/%%; /^$/d'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i want to list the lines that start and end with /* / only, for example consider this input: hi / */ hello ; this is not a valid comment but its gonna be in the output when your command is used. How do i handle this?